# Scrolling to a component on click

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-services, angular-components

Let's say I have a landing page with a button, and I want that when I click on that button I get redirected to another page that has multiple components (imagine a page with a lot of small blocks, each block has a different function) and I want also to be scrolled down to a specific component.

I would want to do that from a service component that gets called whenever I click on that button. How would it be possible to do that?

Here's a dummy, very similar structure of the angular project:

**landing page component html file:**

```
<div class="landingpage-container">
  <magic-button></magic-button>
</div>
```

**button component html file:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <customized-button
   label="MAGIC BUTTON"
   click="goToMagicComponent()"
  >
  </customized-button>
</div>
```

**button component ts file:**

```
imports...
@Component({
  selector: 'magic-button',
  templateUrl: './magic-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./magic-button.component.scss'],
})

export class MagicButtonComponent {
 constructor(
    private magicButtonService: MagicButtonService
  );
 
 goToMagicComponent(): void {
  magicButtonService.goToMagicComponent();
 }
 
}
```

**magic button service ts file:**

```
imports...
export class MagicButtonService {
 //constructor
 goToMagicButtonComponent() {
  //how to scroll to a component inside another component that this service doesn't know about?
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firt, navigate from the component that contains the button to another page.

`main-page.component.html`

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

export class MagicButtonService {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}
    goToMagicButtonComponent() {
        // navigate to another page
        this.router.navigate("otherpage")
    }
}
```

`main-page.component.html`

```
<!-- some code -->
<button (click)="goToMagicButtonComponent()">MAGIC BUTTON</button>
<!-- some code -->
```

Then, on the the component of the other page, implementing `AfterViewInit` you get the element with specific Id, and scroll to that position.

`other-page.component.ts`

```
OtherPageComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const element = document.getElementById("scrollToMe");
        element?.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "start",
          inline: "nearest",
        });
    }
}
```

`other-page.component.html`

```
<!-- some code -->
<app-scrollto-component id="resultadoComponent">
</app-scrollto-component>
<!-- some code -->
```